# Covert Javascript Date to Flutter DateTime

Tags: flutter, dart, datetime

I was wondering how to convert Javascript Date to Flutter DateTime.
I get this Javascript Date `Fri Jun 30 2023 10:09:49 GMT+0930 (Australian Central Standard Time)` from data. I would like to convert it to Flutter DateTime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you'll need the intl package.

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

DateTime convertToFlutterDateTime(String jsDateString) {
  // Parse the date string using the JavaScript-like format
  DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat("EEE MMM d yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'Z",'en_US');
  DateTime parsedDate = dateFormat.parse(jsDateString);
  return parsedDate;
}
```